# How to use image in my ionic app?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I used an image as background in my ionic app using this css code

```
.contentcolor{
  background-image: url('../../assets/Capture3.PNG');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: full;
}
```

But when I run my app on emulator or hard device the image doesn't appear. And when I inspected I found this :

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Where are your images located? I assume in the assets folder? I think you are referencing to a non-existing file.

**EDIT**: Try using: `background-image: url('./../assets/Capture3.PNG');`

Comment: it didn't work, and yes the images are located in src/assets

Comment: background-image: url('./../assets/Capture3.PNG'); might be the solution for you then.